# What's the difference between copydb and clone command in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I can't understand why mongodb has two commands copydb and clone.
Can anyone tell me about these difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know the difference between copydb and clone. Maybe can have better and more informative information

**copydb:**

> 1. The `copydb` run in the admin database of the destination mongod instance. that means in which instance would you like to copy the
>      source DB.
> 2. `copydb` creates the target database if it does not exist in the target instance.
> 3. If database exist but no collection then will copy all collection from source DB to destination DB.
> 4. If any collection exist in destination DB then copydb will return errors and will not copy any remaining collections from the source DB.
> 5. `copydb` **does not lock** the destination server during its operation, so the copy will occasionally `yield` to allow other
>      operations to complete.
> 6. Target DB name can be different from the source DB. like source DB is **simulator** target can be **simulator-backup**.
> 7. It can copy from **primary and/or non-primay** DB from replica.
> 8. Do not use `copydb` to copy databases that contain sharded collections.

**clone:**

> 1. You must run clone on the destination server.
> 2. You unable to set the target DB name as you want that means clone copies the database on the remote instance with the same name as the
>      current database.
> 3. Unable to run in same instance because you are unable to give the different name so if you want to run in the same instance or server
>      will get error.
> 4. clone can copy from a **non-primary** member of a replica set.
> 5. The destination database will be **locked periodically** during the clone operation. In other words, clone will occasionally yield to
>      allow other operations on the database to complete.

So we can see that `copydb` and `clone` has small difference but `copydb` will give you greater flexibility like able to set `todb` and `slaveOk` to copy from primay and secondary. For more can visit [copydb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/copydb/) and [clone](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/clone/#dbcmd.clone)